# Conditional rendering and onClick event using ternary operator

Tags: reactjs, events, onclick, conditional-operator, conditional-rendering

I am trying to show an alert onclick of an element that is conditionally rendered but the onclick event doesn't work i took the code out of the ternary operator and it worked but i cna't seem to find the reason why it didn't work in the ternary operator.

```
import React from 'react';
import HomeIcon from '../Images/home.svg'
import HomeIconBlue from '../Images/home-blue.svg';


function Menubar(props) {
    const style = {
        borderTop: "3px solid #2D79BB",
        color: "#2D79BB",
    }
    return (
        <div className="menu-bar">
            <div className="home-icon">
                {
                    (props.active === 'home') ?
                        <span style={style} onClick={alert('hey')}>
                            <img src={HomeIconBlue} alt="home" />
                            <p>Home</p>
                        </span> :
                        <span>
                            <img src={HomeIcon} alt="home" />
                            <p>Home</p>
                        </span>
                }
            </div>
   )
}

export default Menubar
```

Comment: onClick={e => alert('hey')}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you kept the onClick event is not yet rendered keep it on the second element.
The one currently being rendered

```
return (
        <div className="menu-bar">
            <div className="home-icon">
                {
                    (props.active === 'home') ?
                        <span style={style} >
                            <img src={HomeIconBlue} alt="home" />
                            <p>Home</p>
                        </span> :
                        <span onClick={alert('hey')}>
                            <img src={HomeIcon} alt="home" />
                            <p>Home</p>
                        </span>
                }
            </div>
   )
```

Comment: thanks it worked, i can't believe i made such a silly mistake

Comment: Yeah it happens, have fun

Comment: Thanks once again, we have the same name

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the onClick from

```
onClick={alert('hey')}
```

To

```
onClick={() => alert('hey')}
```